# How do I make ALTER COLUMN idempotent?

Tags: sql-server

I have a migration script with the following statement:

```
ALTER TABLE [Tasks] ALTER COLUMN [SortOrder] int NOT NULL
```

1. What will happen if I run that twice? Will it change anything the second time? MS SQL Management Studio just reports "Command(s) completed successfully", but with no details on whether they actually did anything.
2. If it's not already [idempotent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence), how do I make it so?

Comment: What is `idempotent`?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri Effecively it means run the script again and nothing happens

Comment: Interesting question. I believe this query is already idempotent, but personally I wouldn't go wandering too far down that path (too many rabbit holes to fall down!) Instead have some way of tracking if the entire script has been executed, like a version table (e.g. `_MigrationHistory` in Entity Framework land)

Comment: This is question related to internals of sql server. May be ask it on microsoft site?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say that second time, SQL Server checks metadata and do nothing because nothing has changed.

But if you don't like possibility of multiple execution you can add simple condition to your script:

```
CREATE TABLE Tasks(SortOrder VARCHAR(100));

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
               WHERE [TABLE_NAME] = 'Tasks'
                 AND [COLUMN_NAME] = 'SortOrder'
                 AND IS_NULLABLE = 'NO'
                 AND DATA_TYPE = 'INT')
BEGIN 
  ALTER TABLE [Tasks] ALTER COLUMN [SortOrder] INT NOT NULL
END
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/45f23e/1/0)**</kbd>

Comment: It is not that simple to verify all attributes. What if that column was `varchar` for instance, you need to verify length attribute? What if it was unicode nvarchar etc..

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri So you need to change condition based on `DATA_TYPE` and `CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH` columns. This is not general  condtion. It has to be prepared depending on `ALTER` you want to execute

Answer (score 1):

1. When you execute it the second time, the query gets executed but since the table is already altered, there is no effect. So it makes no effect on the table.
2. No change is there when the script executes twice.

Here is a good MSDN read about: [Inside ALTER TABLE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa224807(v=sql.80).aspx)

> Let's look at what SQL Server does internally when performing an ALTER
>   TABLE command. SQL Server can carry out an ALTER TABLE command in any
>   of three ways:
>
> 1. SQL Server might need to change only metadata.
> 2. SQL Server might need to examine all the existing data to make sure
>      it's compatible with the change but then change only metadata.
> 3. SQL Server might need to physically change every row.